# Pandas count the number of different items within a column of data

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame containing the following (just a sample):

```
Subtype    Cluster
H10N4      59
H10N4      59
H10N4      23
H10N4      59
H3N8       22
H3N8       22
H3N8       44
H3N8       44
```

I want to be able to find out how many different clusters there are for a given subtype. In this case, the desired output is:

```
Subtype    # of Clusters
H10N4      2
H3N8       2
```

I have been doing Pandas, in which I apply a `.groupby('Subtype')` on the dataframe, but after I do that, I'm not sure how to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby('Subtype')
```

and then count the unique clusters in each group:

```
In [12]: g.apply(lambda s: len(s['Cluster'].unique()))
Out[12]:
Subtype
H10N4      2
H3N8       2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: You could also just `groupby(['Subtype', 'Cluster']).size()`

Comment: @AndyHayden true, sorry. But the groupby does doesn't it? This doesn't quite get the right answer though:   _____________________________________________________________________________________________  ``Subtype  Cluster
H10N4    23         1
         59         3
H3N8     22         2
         44           2`` _________________________________________________________________________________________________  (sorry, is there anyway to do code blocks in comments?)

Comment: @joeh There isn't (by design)! Yes, size gets you a MI which has the info you need implicitly, not sure clean way to get from that to desired :s